How to configure bodyParser so it enforce some format on certain field
I have this on the server.js:
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    // This check makes sure this is a JSON parsing issue, but it might be
    // coming from any middleware, not just body-parser:
 
    if (err instanceof SyntaxError && err.status === 400 && 'body' in err) {
        console.error(err);
        return res.status(400).json({status: false, error: 'Please enter valid JSON body'}); // Bad request
    }
 
    next();
 });

So if an invalid JSON is sent, a nice "Please enter valid JSON body" will be displayed, instead of some lines showing invalid token/parsing error. Now I wonder, is there a way to enforce string format within bodyParser?
Example:
{
    "name": "<alert>clive<p>",
    "age": 46,
    "email": "clive99@msn.net"
}

That JSON is valid. But I want name to be alphanumeric string only

No, for that you'll need a validator

Does this answer your question? How to validate request body in Node.js, Express - is it possible without using a library?

You can use Joi

I've been using Joi it's a powerful schema based javascript data validator.
npm i joi

To use Joi with express you have to install one additional dependency express-joi-validation
npm i express-joi-validation

Let's assume /register requires the body data to be in below format
{
    "name": "Clive38", // Alphanum
    "age": 46, // number
    "email": "clive99@msn.net" // email
}

Then create a Joi validation schema for body validation.js
const Joi = require('joi');
const { createValidator } = require('express-joi-validation');

const user_registration_body = Joi.object({
    name: Joi.string()
        .required(), // allows only alphanum
    email: Joi.string()
        .email() // build in email validation
        .required(),
    age : Joi.number().required()
});

const validator = createValidator({ // Create a validator
    passError: true // passes the error to express handler
});

// body method for body validatio
const user_register_body_validation = validator.body(user_registration_body);

module.exports = {
    user_register_body_validation
}

and in app.js we use use user_register_body_validation as a middleware
const { user_register_body_validation } = require('./validation.js')

app.post('/register',user_register_body_validation, your_controller );

Bonus
Since Joi return an array of errors I would recommend to show error response also an array with 400 bad request instead 500
const errorHandler = (err, req, res, next) => {
    if (err.error?.isJoi) { // Specially for validation errors
        let errors = err.error.details.map(e => {
            let res = {
                message: e.message
            };
            return res;
        });
        return res.status(400).json({
            errors // array of errors
        });
    }
    
    // Other errors
    return res.status(500).json({
        error: message: err.message
    });

};

module.exports = errorHandler;

